# How to write modal closing event in React Component Library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, rollup

How to write modal closing event in React Component Library

### Goal

I want to create a modal that can act like antd's modal (https://codesandbox.io/s/7wsxgo?file=/demo.js)

### Problem

There is a small mistake that I think everyone who is new to writing react UI component libraries encounter is how to listen for events to change state correctly.

### What I did

I have built a react UI component using Typescript and I package them with rollup (like webpack) then I publish it on github and download it. Besides that, I use Storybook to manage my components

The modal will show up if the value of props 'visible' is set to true and will hide if it is false
[image: modal image with set true false]

It basically works
[image: Photos used in the gallery]

But how to when the user clicks on the 'X' icon, the modal will hide, I have not been able to do it.

I tried by creating a useState to listen for events from the user. But it gives an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')". There are many people who have the same problem as me (https://dev.to/samiulhsohan/comment/1na7j)

`Modal.tsx`

````
import "./Modal.css";

interface ModalProps {
  visible: boolean;
  title: string;
  contentModal: string;
  okText: string;
  cancelText: string;
  onOk: Function;
}

const Modal = ({
  visible = false,
  title = "Thông báo",
  okText = "Ok",
  cancelText = "Cancel",
  contentModal,
  ...props
}: ModalProps) => {
  const visibleMode = visible ? "defaultModal" : "hidden defaultModal";

  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <div
        id="defaultModal"
        tabIndex={-1}
        aria-hidden="true"
        className={[visibleMode].join(" ")}
      >
        <div className="relative p-4 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
          {/* Modal content */}
          <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            {/* Modal header */}
            <div className="flex justify-between items-start p-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600">
              <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                {title}
              </h3>
              <button
                type="button"
              >
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  className="w-5 h-5"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            {/* Modal body */}
            <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: contentModal }} />
            </div>
            {/* Modal footer */}
            <div>
              <button
                data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"
                type="button"
              >
                {okText}
              </button>
              <button
                data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"
                type="button"
              >
                {cancelText}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {visible && (
        <div className="bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80 fixed inset-0 z-40"></div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;```
````

Answer (score 0):

whenever the next state depends on the previous, it is advised that you pass a callback like this.

```
setState((state)=>!state)
```

this is because react sometimes do batch update asynchronously.

Comment: Hi @Mahmud Suberu, If you download my library, you can use it normally with hooks, but when you create the library, you cannot use hooks in the Modal.tsx file.

Comment: so it works well with useState

Comment: In the App.js file it works because I npm install my library and use it but in the modal.tsx file in the library I wrote we can't use hooks I can only get the props the user passed in to set hindden or open modal